# Eclipse does not recognize the file ID

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create a button in the application from one activity to another. The document `resource/values/strings.xml` created for this ID:

```
<string name="button1name"> CID </ string>
```

But the document GurovPictures.java (this is my main activity) when I insert a line:

```
Button but1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
```

This "button1" does not become blue like "editText1". Do you happen to know how to fix it?   Just the internet no entries found.

Comment: Is the button in the layout.xml of your `GurovPictures.java`?
What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you've created a string resource i.e.

```
 <string name= ...
```

Then you reference it through the string field

```
 String button1 = getString(R.string.button1name);
```